# Are the Raga related question on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are the [Raga](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Raga&oldid=738874295) related question on topic here? I think, questions related to music are on topic because there is a [Upaveda named Gandharvaveda](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Upaveda) that covers music part.

> Gandharvaveda is the study if aesthetics and it speaks of all art-forms like music, dance, poetry, sculpture, and erotica.

As, questions related to music must be on topic here, so does it mean questions related to Raga are also on topic?

Comment: Well, I think if you have a question about Gandharvaveda or the melody of Sama Veda hymns or something like that, then it would be fine.  but if it's a purely music-based question about, say, Bilahari Ragam, I don't think it belongs here; it may be a better fit for http://music.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for replying. Since I have not read Gandharvaveda, so just asking for further clarification. If I ask a question like `What are the Ragas mentioned in Vedas or Upavedas?` Will it be on topic or off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Keshav's [clarification](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/are-the-raga-related-question-on-topic-here#comment2106_634) is good.</sup>
If the raga related question deals with Hinduism i.e Hindu Scriptures then it would be definitely [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); for example questions related to Gandharvaveda and Samveda.

But if the question's aspect leans toward musical system - teaching, practising, etc. or technical and instrumental, then it would be asked on [Music StackExchange](http://music.stackexchange.com) which has tag for [classical](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/indian-classical/info).

[And](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/are-the-raga-related-question-on-topic-here#comment2107_634) yes, I think `What are the Ragas mentioned in Vedas or Upavedas?` would be on-topic here.

Comment: Tanks for clarification.